# Mean absolute difference of two numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, difference

I have two one-dimensional NumPy arrays `X` and `Y`. I need to calculate the mean absolute difference between each element of `X` and each element of `Y`. The naive way is to use a nested `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
Y = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

s = 0
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        s += abs(x - y)
mean = s / (X.size * Y.size)
#3.4399999999999999
```

**Question:** Does NumPy provide a vectorized, faster version of this solution?

**Edited:** I need the mean *absolute* difference (always non-negative). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: just for convenience, I think it's usually helpful to set the seed `np.random.seed(1)` whenever we generate random arrays - that way the answers can exactly reproduce your results.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky fair enough.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that your code generates rank 1 arrays, e.g. (10, ). So, miradulo's code produces the same result as your code for this type of array. However, if your array is of a different shape (2x5) for example, then the results are very different.

Comment: @KRKirov In general, you are right. But that's why I said that my arrays are linear (one-dimensional). Let me clarify this point in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand what your definition is here, you can just use broadcasting.

```
np.mean(np.abs(X[:, None] - Y))
```

Answer (score 4):

Take the difference, then abs, then mean:

```
np.mean(np.abs(X - Y))
```

---

Alternatively:

```
diff = X - Y
abs_diff = np.abs(diff)
mean_diff = np.sum(abs_diff) / (X.size * Y.size)
```

Comment: Neat! But I need the mean _absolute_ difference (always non-negative). Sorry for the confusion. I don't think your solution could be extended to handle abs().

Comment: @DyZ just add `np.abs` to any of the differentiating clauses. `np.abs(X-Y)` or `np.mean(np.abs(X-Y))`

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Nope, it's not the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the same. Take `X=array([8, 4, 6, 0, 9, 2, 3, 2, 9, 4])` and `Y=array([4, 0, 1, 8, 4, 9, 2, 5, 7, 7])`. Your method gives 4.2, the true mean is 3.4. abs() and mean() are not commutative.

Comment: @DyZ fair. I suppose we misunderstood as we assumed the difference between two arrays whereas what you actually meant to ask is the difference between every element in `X` and every element in `Y`

Answer (score 2):

If you tile on opposite axes, then you can `abs` the diff like:

#### Code:

```
x = np.tile(X, (X.size, 1))
y = np.transpose(np.tile(Y, (Y.size, 1)))

mean_diff = np.sum(np.abs(x-y)) / (X.size * Y.size))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
Y = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

s = 0
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        s += abs(x - y)
mean = s / (X.size * Y.size)
print(mean)

x = np.tile(X, (X.size, 1))
y = np.transpose(np.tile(Y, (Y.size, 1)))

print(np.sum(np.abs(x-y)) / (X.size * Y.size))
```

#### Results:

```
3.48
3.48
```